# Open graph story with map and image?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

I'm trying to create an open graph story which will include a map (location) and an image which was uploaded by the user.

So far I've managed to show the map with a pin on it so after the user clicks the pin he see a small popup with the image inside.

How can I make it look more like foursquare - to have a map and the image available for view in full screen?

(Currently my Object inherits from "Object" and I've added a location property to it)